# What is the default number of locks available in Sybase

Tags: sap-ase, database-deadlocks

Sybase is throwing following error "a deadlock has occured or all locks were taken". So I wanted to check if the issue happened because of Sybase running out of available locks.

Does anyone know the default locks available, and also how to find the available number of locks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check..

sp_helpconfig "number of locks:

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read manual about sp_lock, sp_sysmon Lock Management and sp_configure "number of locks" commands.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs156.htm

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs207.htm

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/locking51.htm

Answer (score 0):

As ASE maintains the locks at the server level and i think by default Sybase can handle maximum 5000 locks, using configuration paramter. So probably all 5000 locks has been consumed by your single database objects or objects in different different databases, because after these many locks query starts terminating automatically.